# understanding character level feature_extraction using TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I have set of samples, where each sample have 3 words( given name, middle name, and last name)

```
text = ['James Jackson Jammy',
        'Steve Smith Something',
        'Chamak Chalo Chanta',
        'Polo Rolo Colo']
```

Trying to resolve [issue](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30181/how-to-do-give-input-to-cnn-when-doing-a-text-processing) with inputs for a neural network, I wanted to extract character level tf for the names (ex for james --> ja,am,me,es) and save it as an array to give it to the neural network for classification.

Using [TfIdfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-document-classification-20newsgroups-py), I am trying to extract tf's for a particular word from the corpus

```
# creating the corps
corpus =[]
# splitting the text in to words
corpus = ' '.join(text[i] for i in range(len(text))).split()
# copy only unique words 
corpus = set(corpus)
# creating the character vector (2 letters)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), analyzer= 'char')
X = vectorizer.fit(corpus)
# checking the vector of the one word
# ab = X.transform(['Chamak Chalo Chanta'])
ab = X.transform(['Chamak'])
print(ab.shape)
print(ab)
```

When I am checking the output, I got something like

```
  (1,55)

  (0, 28)   0.38126785705606514
  (0, 27)   0.23541325871187607
  (0, 23)   0.3274372645024392
  (0, 16)   0.28924385126550206
  (0, 15)   0.23541325871187607
  (0, 7)    0.28924385126550206
  (0, 6)    0.23541325871187607
  (0, 4)    0.28924385126550206
  (0, 2)    0.38126785705606514
  (0, 0)    0.4298956344860669
```

It says the shape is (1, 55), and I dont understand what vector it is showing. Is there any meaning for values of (0,0) ...(0,28). For the word 'chamak', I was expecting it should show the tf values for 'ch', 'ha', 'am','ma','ak', but the values are 55 instead of 5.

when I have used `ngram_range=(1,3)` the output is

```
(1, 91)
(0, 49) 0.30927373541425635
(0, 48) 0.30927373541425635
(0, 47) 0.1909605977541359
(0, 42) 0.26560787654230167
(0, 29) 0.30927373541425635
(0, 27) 0.23462645662609066
(0, 26) 0.1909605977541359
(0, 14) 0.23462645662609066
(0, 13) 0.23462645662609066
(0, 12) 0.1909605977541359
(0, 7)  0.30927373541425635
(0, 6)  0.23462645662609066
(0, 3)  0.30927373541425635
(0, 0)  0.34871921735651773
```

When I increase the range to 3 instead of 3 ( like cha, ham, amp, ..) it should decrease but why it is increasing.

My understanding of the concept gone wrong, but did I do wrong? Can I use the vector for inputting to the neural network? For my desired output, tf's for ch, am, ma, ap, pa, ak (6 vectors) is the vector I printed out is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape is (1,55) as 55 is the size of your whole n-gram vocabulary. When you call transform on a list of 1 text, the output shape will still be (1,55), if you called it on 2 texts it would be (2,55). The tuple in your output means that the gram at index (0,x) in your vocabulary is a gram that is in your word. The float is the inverse document frequency

Also i think you misunderstand the way the `ngram_range` parameter works. You ask why it increases, and doesn't decrease when you input (1,3) rather than (1,2). This is because when you input (1,3) it stores both unigrams, bigrams and trigrams in the vocabulary.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot. I have modified the range to ngrams=(2,2) to get the required answer for me.